# Displaying a certain number of columns in Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I have a table containing five columns. How can I display only the first three columns of the table using the number of columns like 3 instead of writing the column name?

Comment: Why would you wish to do that?  This is almost certainly a bad idea and the wrong solution to a problem that you didn't explain here.

Comment: @BrokenCrust, Itz just a curiosity nothing else. I just thought of whether it was possible or not.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that.

You have to list the columns by name. The column "position" has no meaning in a relational database (just like a row does not have a "position").

Comment: That's not quite true. What about `column_id` in `all_tab_cols`? As columns are, **normally**, displayed in the order they're added to a database it's possible to dynamically create a query that would do as @Tauseef is asking. It's just not possible to do it in a single select.

Comment: `column_id` is just a technical detail. In a relational table neither rows nor columns have any ordering. That in reality you do see a certain order has nothing to do with that. The DBMS is free to return columns in any order when using `SELECT *`

Comment: Still not sure [Oracle](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B14117_01/server.101/b10759/statements_10002.htm) explicitly specify that "Oracle Database returns a set of column in the order in which the columns were specified when the object was created." and the [specification of all_tab_cols](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B13789_01/server.101/b10755/statviews_1179.htm) says that `column_id` is "Sequence number of the column as created." It seems that Oracle, as the OP is using, will **always** return columns in the order of the `column_id` in `user_tab_cols`. Unless asked to do otherwise..

Comment: Welk thanx for d info. But I can extract d rows of a table using ROWNUM 

To display a particular no. of rows in a table
-----------------------------------------------
SELECT * FROM employees WHERE ROWNUM <=5